# alerting simple value from js variable

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to alert value of javascript variable like this

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');

alert(id.valueOf());
```

but this alerting only `object Object` even I'm sure that id should contain only one digit number.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: alert(id); is enough to get the value of the variable

Comment: If this is being used for debugging purposes you could also use console.log(id); to get full information on the variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
alert(id);
```

instead of

```
alert(id.valueOf());
```